# Reference repetition at regular intervals

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two Excel sheets (1,2) in a single file and want the data in sheet 2 as follows: `a1(1) a2(2) a3(3)`. I want to reference these data in sheet1 as follows `A2=sheet2!A1`, `A5=sheet2!A2` , `A8=sheet2!A3` and so on.

How do I achieve this?

I tried entering the sequence four times and dragging the formula until the end. Instead of maintaining the sequence, this is what happens:
entered by me:

```
A2=sheet2!A1 A5=sheet2!A2  A8=sheet2!A3
```

on dragging Excel automatically enters:

```
A11=sheet2!A10  A14=sheet2!A11 A17=sheet2!A12 A20=sheet2!A19 A23=sheet2!A20 A26=sheet2!A21
```

What I want:

```
A2=sheet2!A1 A5=sheet2!A2  A8=sheet2!A3
```

If I enter the above one, Excel should automatically enter these formulas:

```
A11=sheet2!A4  A14=sheet2!A5  A17=sheet2!A6  A20=sheet2!A7  A23=sheet2!A8 A26=sheet2!A9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in sheet 1 you want to have formula in cell A2, A5, A8 (i.e. every 3 rows) that reference sheet2 A1,A2,A3 etc.

What do you want in Sheet1 A1,A3,A4,A6 etc? I assume you want them to look blank ie ""

If so, **put this in A2 in Sheet1**.

```
=IF(MOD((ROW(B2)+1),3)=0,OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,QUOTIENT(ROW(B2),3),0),"")
```

or, using the indirect function as suggested elsewhere

```
=IF(MOD((ROW(B2)+1),3)=0,INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&ROUNDUP(ROW(C2)/3,0)),"")
```

This is messy, because you want to copy-down, but you presumable want A3,A4...A6,A7 to be blank.  So you need a way to return a 'blank' cell.

How it works:
MOD( (row(b2)+1),3)  => this give zero for all rows except 2,5,8,11,14 etc etc.

If we are in a 'live' row (A2,A5,A8) then we use offset to move us from Sheet2:A1 down, the rows down only change every 3 cells in Sheet1.

INDIRECT - the other answer just has a typo, but the suggestion is a good one and less volatile than offset:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&ROUNDUP(ROW(C2)/3,0))
```

will give you the right result, but if you copy down you will get repeated values, not blanks. if that is what you want then use the above.

Disclaimer - this is an ugly function for what seems like a weird request. I have to believe you can take a less manual approach to achieve your overall goal, but I think this firs the actual request.

Comment: wow ! worked like a charm ! u are amaizing !! could you also pls show me how i can control the blank cells ? like if i want 10 rowns to be left blank after each entry ?

Comment: =IF(MOD((ROW(B2)-2),10)=0,INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&ROUNDUP(ROW(C2)/10,0)),"")  should work.  The idea is just make cell A2,A12,A22 into something divisible by 10 (for the IF statement).

Comment: could you show me how i can increase or decrease the number of blank between; A2=sheet2!A1 and A5=sheet2!A2 ?

Comment: @Burgertron, you can make this non-volatile like `=IF(MOD(ROW()+1,3)=0,INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,(ROW()+1)/3),"")`

Comment: @burgerton Thank you guys!! you are really amaizing !!! thank you so very much for your help !!! you have just saved me hours and hours of slogging !!

Comment: No problem.  Worth noting what JvdV says above as OFFSET and INDIRECT are what we call 'volatile' functions, this can destroy performance with large/complex files. But you'll need to be careful with first parameter in the Index function to capture the whole range in Sheet2.

Comment: hey ! im so sorry im bugging you with the same thing but is there any way that axcel could do the repeting by itself instead of me dragging the formula . @Burgertron

Comment: dragging the formula is too much work?  You can, in a short period of time, drag the formula thousands of rows!  Or even faster if you select A2:A1000000 and press CTRL-D.  But this is basic skills for moving around the spreadsheet etc, a little outside the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
=INDIRECT("sheet2!A"&ROUNDUP(C2/3,0))
```

Comment: GETTING A #REF COULD YOU PLS EXPLAIN IT SO I DO IT PROPERLY ? IM SORRY IM A COMPLETE NOOB

Comment: A2=sheet2!A1, A5=sheet2!A2, A8=sheet2!A3, A11=sheet2!A4, A14=sheet2!A5, A17=sheet2!A6, A20=sheet2!A7, A23=sheet2!A8, A26=sheet2!A9 UNTILL THE END WHILE SHEET1A3 TO A4 IS BLANK AND A8 TO A10 IS BLANK ... AND SO ON